# Validating UserControl's control by Window's ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

Suppose, I have created custom **LoginForm** as an `UserControl`, which consists of `TextBox` and `PasswordBox`. `TextBox` has installed custom `ErrorTemplate`. Naturally, I would like to have this LoginForm as **reusable** as can, therefore I want to separate validation logic from this LoginForm.

The problem is, that if I **bind** LoginForm's text property to the "validation-property" of the **ViewModel : IDataErrorInfo**, that is set as `Window`'s `DataContext`, the `ErrorTemplate` is not being applied to LoginForm's `TextBox` even if I see debug logs from ViewModel's validator.

How can I validate child controls of reusable component via independent ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of struggling how to solve this, I came up with following solution which satisfies my requirements and so MVVM pattern:

1. Create in `UserControl` a `DepdendencyProperty` of type `IDataErrorInfo` which will be later implemented by your **ViewModel** (for my purposes, I used **ISignUpValidator**:IDataErrorInfo with **UsernameValue** property).
   Lets say this property is registered under the name **Validator** (as default value I used "do-nothing" implementation of my interface).
2. Bind `UserControl`'s `TextBox.Text` property to **Validator** property:
   Lets say `TextBox.Text` property is exposed to `UserControl` under the name 
   **Username**:

   ```
   Username="{Binding Path=Validator.UsernameValue, ElementName=UserControlName,
                                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
   ```
3. Finally **Bind** your **Viewmodel** to your `UserControl`'s **Validator** property

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
       <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
   <Window.Resources>

   <local:LoginForm Validator={StaticResource ViewModel}>
   ```

   Or alternatively, if your **ViewModel** is already set as `Window`'s `DataContext`:

   ```
   <local:LoginForm Validator="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=WindowName}"}>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

use this error template in application resource:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0.8">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="adornerPlaceholder"></AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hi, I have already one custom ErrorTemplate that works on textbox if i perform validation on control level. My problem is, that i would like to move validation on higher level. It seems, that usercontrol's child control is not aware of it's parent's error. I'm searching for some solution how to accomplish this.